# git fatal: bad object when cherry-pick commit from another remote

Tags: git

i have this situation with two remote repos:

```
my-repo
  -master
  -mybranch (branch-to-cherry-pick-to)

other-repo
  -master (branch-to-cherry-pick-from)
```

so i want to get some cherry-picks from the other remotes master branch into mybranch.

I have added another remote by doing: `git add remote other-origin somegitrepo` and verified with `git remote -v` which showed my output like this:

```
origin my-repo (fetch)
origin my-repo (push)
other-origin other-repo (fetch)
other-origin other-repo (push)
```

Now when i try to `git cherry-pick commitnr` i get the `fatal: bad object`
Error.

The commits i want to cherry pick btw: https://github.com/wekan/wekan/pull/1003/commits

I also did `git fetch --all`

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 6):

Did you missed a `merge` after `fetch`?

Try:

```
$ git pull
$ git cherry-pick ...
```